# Separate string in cluster strings of repeated values in same order as they appear in original string

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

I have a string with two characters. I need to separate the string into little clusters of the characters when they are grouped together.
Let's say my string is 
`"xxxxxxxxyyxyxxxxyyyyyxyxxxxyyyyyyyxyyxyyyyyxyyyxxxyyyyxyyy"`

I need now an array, a list, whatever that reads like: 
`[["xxxxxxxx"],["yy"],["x"],["y"],["xxxx"],["yyyyy"],["x"],["y"],["xxxx"],["yyyyyyy"],["x"],["yy"],["x"],["yyyyy"],["x"],["yyy"],["xxx"],["yyyy"],["x"],["yyy"]]`

I need to keep the order, as I would iterate it and then make changes in the clusters accordingly. I just can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Do you know before hand these 2 characters? Or they are random ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you have letters "x" and "y" you can use RegExp pattern

> (x+|y+)

to find your clusters.

```
    public String[] separateString(String s, String firstSymbol, String secondSymbol){
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + firstSymbol + "+|" + secondSymbol + "+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while(matcher.find()){
            l.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return l.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

If you have special characters for regular expressions, like "+" or ".", you need to screen them in this solution:

```
    String s = "+++---";
    String first = "\\+";
    String second = "-";
    String[] result = separateString(s, first, second);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to scan the string from start to end and check for continuous `x`s and `y`s and collect them.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
   int sz = list.size();
   int j = i;
   while ( i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == 'x' ) i++;
   if ( i > j )  list.add(s.substring(j,i));
   j = i;
   while ( i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == 'y' ) i++;
   if ( i > j ) list.add(s.substring(j,i));
   if ( sz == list.size() ) i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: See SomeDude's answer, much better than mine was.

If wanted, SomeDude's answer can be generalised for any number of symbols:

```
List<String> clusters = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < s.length();)
{
    int j = i;
    while(i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) i++;
    if(i > j) clusters.add(s.substring(j, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just scan over the string with a single for loop. Just check with the previous character. If they are same, continue, else add the previous substring to result. You can make use of a pointer variable, say `start` which denotes from where the previous substring starts. Below code also works for any kind of chars other than just `x` and `y`.

**Snippet:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "xxxxxxxxyyxyxxxxyyyyyxyxxxxyyyyyyyxyyxyyyyyxyyyxxxyyyyxyyy";
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<s.length();++i){
            if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i-1)){
                res.add(s.substring(start,i));
                start = i;
            }
        }
        res.add(s.substring(start,s.length())); // to add last unadded substring of same characters
        System.out.println(res.toString());
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://onlinegdb.com/SkRqmAQQU